# Can't capture video from Samsung S5 using adb screenrecord

Tags: android, adb

Here is my command and the output:

```
shell@kltexzy:/sdcard $ screenrecord --verbose tmp.mp4                         
Main display is 1080x1920 @44.70fps (orientation=0)
Configuring recorder for 1080x1920 video at 4.00Mbps
ERROR: unable to configure codec (err=-2147483648)
WARNING: failed at 1080x1920, retrying at 720x1280
Configuring recorder for 720x1280 video at 4.00Mbps
Aborted
shell@kltexzy:/sdcard $
```

The "Aborted" message is displayed after about 10 seconds.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724058/try-to-video-record-using-adb-shell-screenrecord-android-4-4) is not the problem because I am not using an emulator.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514457/i-cant-capture-android-screen-using-adb-screen-record-tool) is a different error code.

The Galaxy S5 is brand new, just out of the box.

I tried different bit-rates and different screen sizes but that did not work.

Is adb screenrecord supported on this device?  Everything I has so far read says that the only requirement for screenrecord is KitKat, which this device has.

Comment: I got the exact same thing with my s4, same errors. Way too little docs on this feature yet, I can't find any info anywhere. A list of devices where it's confirmed it works would be nice!

Comment: have you tried setting the video path to the sdcard?

like `adb shell screenrecord <args> /sdcard/temp.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

Turning off power save mode fixes it. Power save lowers the screen's frame rate, causing screenrecord binary to fail.

Hope this helps.